# Is it possible to use Lisp syntax and prefix notation in C?

Tags: c, macros, lisp

Is it possible somehow using C macros to make prefix notation and/or Lisp syntax? For example, I want to write `(f a b)` instead of `f(a, b);` for C compiler.
Just for fun!

Comment: I suppose you can just use ECL.

Comment: It would be trivial to write a parser that input prefix and output something that can be compiled if the functions were defined but I don't think you can make the C preprosessor do that transformation.

Comment: This is called [preprocessor abuse](http://c-faq.com/cpp/slm.html). Write C if you use C and Lisp when you use Lisp, you will save a lot of grief to all readers of your code, starting with yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the Lisp language, especially in the ANSI-Specified Common Lisp dialect, the manner in which processing of code occurs is much different from that of a C/C++ compiler, and this allows for Common Lisp macros to do -- and furthermore, to **be** -- something completely different from macros in other, non-Lisp languages.

Lisp interpretation has three stages.  First is the read phase, during which code is read and certain defined characters are expanded into Common Lisp code.

1) Read Time -- during this stage, all defined, dispatched, etcetera, macro *characters* are expanded into common lisp forms/code to be evaluated later.
2) Compile Time -- during this stage, all definitions take place and procedures are stored into memory in a (perhaps) specified namespace with given names by which to reference them during:
3) Run Time -- during this time, the program is essentially running, and all that is left is to call the procedures constructed in phases 1 & 2 inside the Lisp REPL.

Interpreted languages are much more likely to support the insane customization options Common Lisp's macro definition system affords us. For example, I can quite easily change my REPL such that if I feed it the following form:

> CL_USER>  (progn (sleep 10) (format *standard-output* "~%~%10 seconds have passed and the universal timestamp is now ~a~%~%" (get-universal-time))&

...I may have defined the character #\& as to take the expression it closes, write it into a lambda function, and put that function into a threaded process, giving the REPL/prompt back to the user immediately and 10 seconds later (allowing interpretation the entire time) format a short message to the standard output.

Unfortunately, C & C++ just aren't really built for this sort of customization.

Whatever it is that you're doing, I imagine the answer to be "do the entire thing in Common Lisp" quite honestly, and I don't say that out of bias or elitism, but out of simple experience and the benefit of years of observation.

While I'm close to it, let me just call it what it is and end on *absolute subjective opinion*: I've observed that all programmers I respect and who are doing work that is worthy of respect in the hacker community eventually end up using Common Lisp as their primary mode of operation.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible somehow using C macros to make prefix notation and/or
>   Lisp syntax?

Probably.

> For example, I want to write (f a b) instead of f(a, b); for C
>   compiler

[No, you do not want to do that.](http://c-faq.com/cpp/slm.html)

> Just for fun!

Enjoy [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/)